Add a field to Woocommerce checkout doesn't work
I need to add a field with company name to my checkout in WordPress WooCommerce.
First, I tried this code example:
add_action('woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'true_custom_checkout_field' );
function true_custom_checkout_field() {      
    echo 'Однажды тут будет поле.';  
}

But nothing happened. Then I installed Checkout Field Editor for WooCommerce and Checkout Manager, both didn't work.
Is it a problem with my free theme called "Boutique Designer Shop"?

This is because WooCommerce enable now by default Cart and Checkout Blocks, that only allow very few customizations… You need to switch back to classic WooCommerce Cart and Checkout (shortcodes).

For some resason, I tap "transform to shortcode" and then it transforms to blocks again

Automatically transforms

No, I made a mistake. Its ok
